# Can I decode an md5 code without knowing the one character?

Tags: md5

How can I decode this MD5 hash, if I don't know where a char is missing? `0fa605e479e7cd896f9bc33cccba944`

Comment: Being able to decode it is counter-intuitive of its function. So, NO.

Comment: MD5 is a hash function - it is a one-way transformation. You can't decode it, doubly so if there's a character missing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hacking a hashed value.

Comment: @MikeW You can't simply imply that he is trying to 'hack' something.

Answer (score 2):

You can sometimes "decode" an MD5 hash using a rainbow table. This is basically a list of every possible combination of letters/numbers and the resulting hash values. This is not really "decoding" per se, but it is effectively the same thing.

Here's one sample:

https://crackstation.net/

However, with a missing character, it's really impossible.  Too many variations even to look up in a rainbow table.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the missing character.

There are 16 possible values that the character could take (0-f), and there are 32 possible positions that the character could take. This means there are 16 * 32 = 512 different combinations to try.

Secondly, the "decoding".

MD5 is a hash function, which means it is designed to be a one way transformation and can't be decoded. *However*, MD5 used to be very popular for storing passwords so people have created databases of the hashed values for doing reverse lookups.

If you were super keen and you think the original value might be a dictionary word, you could do a reverse lookup on all 512 possibilites.